# does PDOException class inherits Exception class?

Tags: php, database, pdo, transactions

I'm writing a pdo php transaction code and i keep writing the catch part like that:

```
try{
        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        //Some transaction code
        $this->db->endTransaction();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $this->db->cancelTransaction();
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        $this->db->cancelTransaction();
    }
```

The code works well but I feel like this is not logical. is it enough to just use the catch(Exception $e) and remove the catch(PDOException $e) part? does the PDOException class inherits the Exception class?

Comment: in exception handling, you should allways be as precise as possible. `Exception` could catch any kind of exception, and for a, let's say, `ScriptFailedForSomeRandomReasonUnrelatedToYourDatabase`, the error-handling of cancelling your databasetransaction would not do any good.

Comment: [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) extends [RuntimeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) which extends [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php). But as Franz said, if you only catch Exception, you could be catching more than you expect.

Comment: @PatrickQ that's what you probably want to rollback a transaction

Comment: thanks bro, that still doesn't answer my question. regarding to my database i should cancel this transaction for any possible failure of any part of the code.

Comment: If you're trying to catch multiple exception types with different handling for each, then the order of your catches is important.... in this case, and PDOException extends Exception (no matter indirectly) you'll always catch Exception and never the specific PDOException.... specifics first, then general exceptions for multiple catch blocks

Comment: thanks for the notes :) but let me rewrite the main question does removing the catch(PDOException $e) part change any of the result of the code above?

Comment: Removing the catch for PDOException won't have any effect on the code logic that you've posted, as a PDOException will be caught by the catch for Exception anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it inherits. Yes, it's not logical. Yes, is it enough to just use the catch(Exception $e)

Answer (score 0):

[PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) extends [RuntimeException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) which extends [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php). So your code is not logical, second catch will not work never. It is enough to just use the `catch(Exception $e)`. But if you want handle differently, you need to do in a following way

```
<?php
    try {
      $this->db->beginTransaction();
      //Some transaction code
      $this->db->endTransaction();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "DataBase Error:".$e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "General Error".$e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can't you please think of any handling scenario other than just silly echo? There are so many such examples around that every single PHP noob is thinking that echo $e->getMessage(); is the only purpose of catch ever.

Comment: I can but it is just an example.